# Particle を with missing verb

Tags: grammar, particle-を, ellipsis

> 次の作品を最後に筆を折るつもりです
> I plan to give up writing after my next piece

I asked a similar question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/87129/use-of-suffix-%E5%BE%8C-in-place-of-a-verb), but I don't think the same explanation applies (I may be missing something).

There is no verb to go with the first を in this sentence. I can only imagine that something like 書いてから has been omitted. How should I understand the grammar of this sentence?

Also, does the sentence sound as pretentious as I think it does, or is this a natural thing to say?

Comment: if it said 最後にして would it make better sense to you?

Comment: @A.Ellett Ah, yes. That would make perfect sense, thanks. Don't know why I didn't think of that. I'm minded to delete the question, unless you want to turn your comment into an answer.